# Programmatically setting two TextView side-by-side in LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

So, I am iterating through a `HashMap` of Strings and Booleans. I am placing a TextView on the LinearLayout for each String. This is all good. What I need to do is place a TextView of the Boolean value **to the right** of each String TextView. Any ideas? This is what I am looking for...

[image]

```
LinearLayout planLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.planLayout);
for (Map.Entry<String, Boolean> entry : plans.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Boolean value = entry.getValue();
    TextView keyTV = new TextView(this);
    keyTV.setText(key + " | ");
    // here is where I want to set a TextView of the Boolean to the right of the keyTV
    planLayout.addView(keyTV);
}
```

**Updated using ClickableSpan**

```
    LinearLayout planLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.planLayout);

    for (Map.Entry<String, Boolean> entry : plans.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Boolean value = entry.getValue();
        TextView keyTV = new TextView(this);
        SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(value.toString());
        ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View textView) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "clicked",
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                System.out.println("Hello");
            }
        };
        ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, 0, 4, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        keyTV.setText(key + " | " + ss);
        keyTV.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        keyTV.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20);
        planLayout.addView(keyTV);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `LinearLayout` can only be laid in one direction: vertically, in this case. From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html):

> A Layout that arranges its children in a single column or a single
>   row. The direction of the row can be set by calling `setOrientation()`.

While you could nest another horizontal `LinearLayout` (one for each item) and add the TextViews as its children, in this case it would seem to be much simpler to just concatenate the value into the same TextView object.

If you need only part of the text to be clickable, you can use [`ClickableSpan`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html) to achieve this (remember to use `setMovementMethod()` too, for it to work).

Comment: I have done this, but the right side (the boolean value) will eventually be clickable, where as the left won't be. Therefore, I need them to be separated

Comment: Thanks for the tip on ClickableSpan. Will check it out.

Comment: @Harry you can use spanned strings to make only part of the textview clickable. Or, alternatively, nest layouts.

Comment: I am trying to use ClickableSpan and it seems like it is only working when ONLY that span is in the TextView: `   keyTV.setText(ss);` but when I do this `   keyTV.setText(key + " | " + ss);` then the span is no longer clickable. What am I doing wrong? I have updated the original question, by the way. Thanks again for the help

Comment: Actually, I got it. Didn't think to set the SpannableString to the entire string, not just the boolean. Thanks again!